# Facing Notion API problem while trying updating databases properties: can't update checkbox

Tags: notion-api, notion-js

with Notion API and node.js, I'm trying to update database properties, especially the **checkbox** property, for my routine ToDo tasks checker.

But I couldn't find the correct way to do so. Error messages say my setting of the checkbox property isn't correct, but I couldn't find the right way in the [Notion API documents](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page).

Here's my code:

```js
const { Client } = require("@notionhq/client");
require("dotenv").config();
const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_KEY });
const databaseId = process.env.NOTION_DATABASE_ID;

const uncheckRoutineTasksTodo = async () => {
    const response = await notion.databases.update({
        database_id: databaseId,
        icon:{//Worked
            type:"emoji",
            emoji:""
        },
        properties: {
            Done: {
                checkbox: false,
            },
        },
    });
    console.log(response);
};
uncheckRoutineTasksTodo();
```

And error messages are:

```
@notionhq/client warn: request fail {
  code: 'validation_error',
  message: 'body failed validation. Fix one:\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.formula should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.rollup should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.checkbox should be an object, instead was `false`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.created_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.created_time should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.last_edited_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.last_edited_time should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.properties.Done.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
}
```

As messages suggest, I tried to transform the checkbox property to object, but the result was the same.

```js
properties: {
        Done: {
            checkbox: {
                checkbox:false
                }
           },
    },
```

```
body.properties.Done.checkbox should be an object, instead was `false`.
```

Does someone know how to set checkbox property correctly? Please bail me out…

Comment: I am seeing this kind of errors as well - did you fix your issue?

Comment: Not still... I looked up but no one mentioned significantly updating checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `notion.pages.update()` instead `notion.databases.update()`. Each entry of a database is called a 'page', so you want to modify that, rather than the database itself.

As per the Notion API docs, an example would be:

```
const { Client } = require('@notionhq/client');

const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_API_KEY });

(async () => {
  const pageId = {YOUR_PAGE_ID};
  const response = await notion.pages.update({
    page_id: pageId,
    properties: {
      'In stock': {
        checkbox: true,
      },
    },
  });
  console.log(response);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Exploring in the `notion.databases.update()`type definition, there're types info about each params. And in `checkbox` property, I find these below:

```
declare type UpdateDatabaseBodyParameters = {
   | null | {
        checkbox: EmptyObject;
        type?: "checkbox";
        name?: string;
    } 
}
```

checkbox param should be `EmptyObject`. That's why the compiler shows the error I got, `body.properties.Done.checkbox should be an object`.

Then, I digged into `EmptyObject` type definition, and that's here:

```
declare type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>;
```

`Record<key, value>` is an object type definition that has types `{key : value}`.

Getting back to the issue, `EmptyObject` is an object that accepts `{string: never}`. And indeed, type `never` does not accept any types. Therefore I can set nothing inside the object as a property.

In conclusion, I couldn't find a way to mutate the `checkbox` property already being on the exixsed DB through API.

If someone know the appropriate way, please let me know...

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same Problem and the solution to past an empty object. So for example        `properties: { Done: { checkbox: {}, },`

And in the update the property can be true or false